# Using IFNULL in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with an SQL statement not returning any result from a specific result.

```
    SELECT statementbalance AS 'BringForwardFromPreviousDay', 
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(statementdebit) FROM statement WHERE merchantid = '4' AND statementdate = '2018-01-08'),0) AS 'TotalDebit',
IFNULL((SELECT SUM(statementcredit) FROM statement WHERE merchantid = '4' AND statementdate = '2018-01-08'),0) AS 'TotalCredit',
IFNULL((SELECT statementbalance FROM statement WHERE merchantid = '4' AND statementdate <= '2018-01-08' ORDER BY transactionid DESC LIMIT 1),0) AS 'TotalBalance'
FROM statement 
WHERE merchantid = '4' and statementdate <= '2018-01-07'
ORDER BY transactionid DESC LIMIT 1
```

The SQL statement is to capture data dated from today `'2018-01-08'`and from previous days `'2018-01-07'` and grab the last recorded data hence the `'<='`
Because `merchantid = '4'` is a newly added merchant, it does not have any data to grab from `<= 2018-01-07` hence i want it to return `0` instead of `null` and prevent other data from returning `null`.

I tried adding `ifnull` on the `statementnbalance` but it still returns `null` and i can only think of including `ifnull` on the `where` clause but i tried to no avail.

Here is the sqlfiddle of using `merchantid '2'` that works fine.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7cae3e0/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select
    x.merchantid                       as merchantid,
    ifnull(c.previous_days_balance, 0) as BringForwardFormPreviousDay,
    ifnull(a.latest_total_debit, 0)    as TotalDebit,
    ifnull(a.latest_total_credit, 0)   as TotalCredit,
    ifnull(b.latest_balance, 0)        as LatestBalance
from
    (
        select distinct merchantid from statement
    ) x
    left outer join
    (
        select
            merchantid, 
            sum(statementdebit) as latest_total_debit,
            sum(statementcredit) as latest_total_credit
        from
            statement
        where
            statementdate = '2018-01-08'
        group by
            merchantid
    ) a
    on x.merchantid = a.merchantid
    left outer join
    (
        select
            merchantid,
            statementbalance as latest_balance
        from
            statement
        where
            (merchantid, transactionid) in
            (
                select
                    merchantid,
                    max(transactionid)
                from
                    statement
                where
                    statementdate = '2018-01-08'
                group by
                    merchantid
            )
    ) b
    on x.merchantid = b.merchantid
    left outer join
    (
        select
            merchantid,
            statementbalance as previous_days_balance
        from
            statement
        where
            (merchantid, transactionid) in
            (
                select
                    merchantid,
                    max(transactionid)
                from
                    statement
                where
                    statementdate <= '2018-01-07'
                group by
                    merchantid
            )
    ) c
    on x.merchantid = c.merchantid;
```

I added another row to illustrate the extra case:

```
INSERT INTO statement VALUES ('99', '5', '131', 'Purchase: TopUp Cheezy', '2018-01-05', '23:35:31', '38.20', '0.00', '5000.00');
```

The results are:

```
+------------+-----------------------------+------------+-------------+----------------+
| merchantid | BringForwardFormPreviousDay | TotalDebit | TotalCredit | LatestBalance  |
+------------+-----------------------------+------------+-------------+----------------+
|          1 |                          35 |         15 |           0 |              5 |
|          2 |                      182.33 |        4.9 |           0 |         177.43 |
|          4 |                           0 |      95.48 |         200 |         104.52 |
|          5 |                        5000 |          0 |           0 |              0 |
+------------+-----------------------------+------------+-------------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This assumes that transactionId keeps on increasing with time.  That is not an entirely safe assumption.  It would be better to use timestamps rather than dates for the transaction so you can find the latest one (or the latest one that is before today).  I see that you do have statementtime but a separate column...

Comment: thanks but i only need one specific merchant as i will be using php to push for other merchants in seperate tables. which part of the sql statement lets me choose one specific merchant?

Comment: So add the specific merchant in each of the where clauses.  The principle is still the same.  You need the sum of debits and credits for the day, the latest statement balance for the day and the latest balance for the previous day - hence 3 sub queries.  You need the outer join because there may or may not be a balance for the previous day.

Comment: Okay i found a bug using this method, what if there is a specific date when there is no statement added for that day. But records of previous day is there. It gives me null. I need the result to show on bring forward from previous days(which grabs from last record of statementbalance of that the previous day) and latest balance shows same value for those days with the where `merchantid = 'something'`

Comment: Normally, the latest previous balance, whenever that was would be valid, so for merchants 1 you'd want the balance from 2017-01-06.  I'll modify the query to do that, if that's what you want here.

Comment: So I changed "= 2018-01-07" to "<= '2018-01-07'" in sub-query "c", and that works, but note the warning about relying on transactionId to give you a time sequence.

Comment: I just tried and it still doesnt work. I got a null result on days where theres no statement. Do note that the data included in the sqlfiddle is just a portion of a big number of data that i have. I only added whats necessary. Here's the expected result to get again https://ibb.co/bEMiuG

Comment: That's a different problem.  You can either do an outer join from a merchant table (assuming you have one), so that you get a merchant even if he has no statement on the day being selected, or get the merchant id, without restriction, from the statement table (less efficient) and then outer join from there, or handle this in the php code.

Comment: Okay provided that a merchant does exist which it does by the way and what links it is only `merchant.merchantid = statement.merchantid` Where should i change? Do u want me to sqlfiddle u a merchant table i use too?

Comment: Just noticed your comment on merchant table.  It would be better to substitute that for the statement table in sub-query x.

Comment: @Anonymous Vagrant.  I have responded to the third iteration of this question.  Is it as it should be now?  If so, could I have the green check mark back, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164133/discussion-between-anonymous-vagrant-and-ron-ballard).

Answer (score 1):

The query doesn't return anything because there are no data to return that fit your where clause. What you could do is using an `IFNULL` on your whole select statement:

```
SELECT ifnull((SELECT statementbalance AS 'BringForwardFromPreviousDay'
               FROM statement 
               WHERE merchantid = '4'
                   AND statementdate <= '2018-01-07'
               ORDER BY transactionid DESC LIMIT 1), 0)
```

and work from there. However, your statement can only contain one column, so you either have to work this into a stored procedure, or you have to deal with this issue at a different place (maybe in your code?)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` to allow for rows that don't exist.

```
SELECT IFNULL(t3.statementbalance, 0) AS BringForwardFromPreviousDay,
        t1.TotalDebit, t1.TotalCredit, t2.TotalBalance
FROM (SELECT SUM(statementdebit) AS TotalDebit,
             SUM(statementcredit) AS TotalCredit
      FROM statement
      WHERE merchantId = '4' AND statementdate = '2018-01-08') AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT statementbalance AS TotalBalance
      FROM statement
      WHERE merchantId = '4' AND statementdate <= '2018-01-08'
      ORDER BY statementdate DESC
      LIMIT 1) AS t2
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT statementbalance
    FROM statement 
    WHERE t3.merchantID = '4' AND t3.statementdate <= '2018-01-07'
    ORDER BY statementdate DESC
    LIMIT 1) ON 1=1
```

Comment: this works on data that does not have rows that dont exist previously but it does not work on rows that exist before the date. The latter will show a list of records which is not the intended result. The result should only display one row hence `LIMIT 1`

Comment: OK,changed that